# Kill a SPID on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a rogue SPID on a MS SQL Server 2008.

Is there a way to kill it without restarting the server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[KILL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx)

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where violence *is* the answer.

Comment: @splattne: I should flag your comment for moderator review because it is glorifying violence, shouldn't I? ;)

Comment: @abaumg ☮ man...